# Deserialise CDATA values

Tags: xslt

As part of our coding, we need to fetch values from a string which is capsulated in CDATA function.
Unfortunately Datapower doesnot recognise CDATA as a valid XSL function.

Is there anyway in XSL Programming, i can deserialise the string and take the needed values.

Comment: XSLT will just see the values in the CDATA section - when you access the element what do you get? CDATA just escapes characters in the element.

Comment: Yes, my XPATH is able to point to the fields..but that XPATH results in empty string in output. No value is being fetched into it. Please suggest.

Comment: Any way i can do this, please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used DP:PARSE function in Datapower and thus able to deserialise it. Thanks.